# Handle large dataset and train a model

Tags: python, bigdata, classification, large-data

I have a big sound dataset formed by 550k sounds! I have already all the metadata stored and I would like to use this dataset for building a classification model.

Do you have any suggestions about how to handle a big dataset? I have always worked with a maximum of 2000 sounds! Never done it with that much data.

I would like to ask you if there are some tools or something for doing this task.

I normally use a data generator, pandas and Keras but I guess that this way is not the best solution in this case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can search for `tf.data.Dataset`.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Tensorflow's dataset API.